# How one can achieve late binding in C language?

Tags: c, binding, dynamic-linking

How one can achieve late [binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding) in C language ?

Comment: How about using an array of function pointers. We can then choose the function pointer from array based on user input

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Late binding is not really a function of the C language itself, more something that your execution environment provides for you.

Many systems will provide deferred binding as a feature of the linker/loader and you can also use explicit calls such as `dlopen` (to open a shared library) and `dlsym` (to get the address of a symbol within that library so you can access it or call it).

The only semi-portable way of getting late binding with the C standard would be to use some trickery with `system()` and even that is at least partially implementation-specific.

If you're not so much talking about deferred binding but instead polymorphism, you can achieve that effect with function pointers. Basically, you create a `struct` which has all the data for a type along with function pointers for locating the methods for that type. Then, in the *"constructor"* (typically an *init()* function), you set the function pointers to the relevant functions for that type.

You still need to include all the code even if you don't use it but it *is* possible to get polymorphism that way.

Answer (score 3):

Symbol binding in C is always done at compile time, never runtime.

Library binding, or dynamic linking as it's called, is done via `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` on *nix, and `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

> How one can achieve late binding in C language ?

The closest would be through dynamic loading of library (DLL) such as with **[dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)** & **[dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym)** on Linux. Otherwise, it is not directly available in `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Objective-C or Lua. Both are late-bound languages which can easily interface with C.

Of course you could implement your own name resolution scheme, but why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you did not specify an OS. For Unix you can use shared libraries, or create a configurable (plugin) module structure. For details you may find the source code of an apache 1.3 webserver useful. http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

Answer (score 0):

cppdev seems to be the one and only to hit the spot with his/her remark.
Please, have a look at [the definition itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding). In a few words:

> Late binding, or dynamic binding, is a computer programming mechanism
>   in which the method being called upon an object is looked up by name
>   at runtime.

All other answers just miss the main point, that is "look up by name".

The needed solution would be very similar to a lookup table of pointers to functions along with a function or two to select the right one by name (or even by signature). We call it a "hash table".